What are the default code anotation keywords for Python in VS Code?
I can see that VS Code highlights some keywords like TODO and NOTE in Python code annotations. How can I get a list of the keywords highlighted by default?

These keyword annotations are provided by Microsoft's Python extension. In version 2024.14.1, the extension provides:

NOTE
XXX
HACK
FIXME
BUG and
TODO

These keywords can be found in the file <vs_code_directory>/extensions/resources/app/extensions/python/syntaxes/MagicPython.tmLanguage.json. Use find to locate one of these words (e.g. Ctrl + F NOTE) and the others will be OR'ed right next to it. In Windows, vs_code_directory is %LocalAppData%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\.
Related links:

Visual Studio Code Grammar files location

VS Code Syntax Highlight Guide


